# Generators of a non-orthonormal Clifford algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras

In the case of orthonormal Clifford Algebra, matrix representations of the generators are easy to find. For example, in 3d-Euclidean space,

$$
\frac{1}{2} \left( \sigma_i \sigma_j +\sigma_j \sigma_i \right) = \delta_{i j}
$$

The generators are the Pauli matrices.

However, in the case of non-orthonormal algebras, what can and cannot serve as a representation is unclear to me. Suppose the following Clifford Algebra

$$
\frac{1}{2} \left( e_\mu e_\nu+e_\nu e_\mu \right) = g_{\mu\nu}
$$

Can we find matrix representations for $e_\nu, e_{\mu}$? If not, what can we use?

Edit: example

For example, one can think of the interval (metric tensor) of general relativity

$$
e_0e_0=g_{00}\\
e_1e_1=g_{11}\\
e_2e_2=g_{22}\\
e_3e_3=g_{33}\\
e_0e_1+e_1e_0=2g_{01}\\
e_0e_2+e_2e_0=2g_{02}\\
e_0e_3+e_3e_0=2g_{03}\\
e_1e_2+e_2e_1=2g_{12}\\
e_1e_3+e_3e_1=2g_{13}\\
e_2e_3+e_3e_2=2g_{23}
$$

Is there a valid matrix representation of the generators $e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3$?

Comment: What is an “orthonormal algebra”?

Comment: @rschwieb an algebra whose generators are: $\frac{1}{2} \left( \sigma_i \sigma_j +\sigma_j \sigma_i \right) = \delta_{i j}$

Comment: Who uses this term? I have trouble seeing its usefulness. It looks like a real Clifford algebra is “orthonormal” iff the signature of its metric is positive definite, and that every complex Clifford algebra for a non degenerate metric is “orthonormal”.

Comment: @rschwieb I would think that if the quadratic form contains cross-terms, it would be non-orthonormal.

Comment: if you give me an example, I could consider it with you.

Comment: @rschwieb Alright, I added an example as an edit to the question.

Comment: "Is there a valid matrix representation of the generators?"  Isn't this a separate and trivial question? You can represent any finite dimensional algebra with matrices...  I thought the point was to find a basis that satisfied your "orthonormality" condition.

Comment: We can always construct a different set of basis vectors (generators) for which the cross-terms disappear, by a simple modification of the Gram-Schmidt process. (Let's ignore fields of characteristic $2$.) In this sense, any Clifford algebra is "orthogonal", if not "orthonormal". I put these in quotes because they ought to refer to a basis, not to the algebra itself.

Answer (score 1):

Every finite dimensional algebra can be represented as an algebra of matrices.

If you let $V$ be the underlying vector space of a $k$ algebra, then each element $a\in V$ acts by left multiplication on $V$, creating a linear transformation $\lambda_a$ of $V$.

The mapping $a\mapsto \lambda_a\in End_k(V)\cong M_{\dim(V)}(k)$ turns out to be a homomorphism of $k$-algebras, and its image is an algebra of matrices isomorphic to the original algebra.

Comment: Can you produce a specific matrix basis that satisfies the example?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Why would one leave the bilinear form in terms of $g_{ij}$'s?  Why wouldn't you choose a basis to diagonalize it?

Comment: It is not mathematically hard, but a bit tedious to write out $16$ $16\times 16$ matrices for the example you requested, at least for the diagonalized case. Doing it with the $g$'s would be very messy.